# Arduino native USB port and Simulink

Tags: serial, usb, arduino-due, communication

I am trying to communicate through the native USB port of the Arduino Due with a PC.

The native port itself works, I have tested this. The problem is, that every time I upload my Simulink model via the programming port onto the Arduino, Windows loses the connection to the native (Bossa) port.

It does not recocnize the port anymore after programming the Arduino with Simulink (Arduino Support Package). The only way to get Windows to recognise the port again is holding reset+erase on the Arduino, which obviously deletes my application.

Do you know any solution? Is this possible to get the native port working for communication after using Simulink to deploy my application?

Comment: ditch simulink for arduino programming and use arduino ide and code?  simulink should be able to produce C code you can then patch into the ide in the form of headers.

Comment: the native USB is handled by the program running in the MCU. if you upload a program which doesn't do it or doesn't work at all, then there will be no working USB on native port

Comment: Are you initializing a serial connection in the Simulink code? If not there won't be one and you loose connection when the actual code starts. The main code needs to do that.please show us what you have got in Simulink. Though it might be that we cannot help you since we are no experts in Simulink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working myself by simply writing the communication part in C for the Due, not using the Simulink blocks.